# Avoid that keyframe animation overflows submenus in navigation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have the following `HTML` and `CSS` which you can also find in the JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vu0hnqab/129/):

```css
/* Header & Naviagtion */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  position: fixed;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.navigation>ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: purple;
}

.panel {
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
}

.button:hover .panel {
  transform: scale(1);
}



/* Content Animation */

.parent{
 margin-top: 5%;
 height: 10%;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
 
.content1{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
}
 
 .content2{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
 animation-delay: 1s;
  position: absolute;
}
 
 .content3{ 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:yellow;
 float: left;
 animation-delay: 2s;
 position: absolute;
}
 
.content4{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%; 
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
 animation-delay: 3s;
 position: absolute;
}
 
.content5{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: lime;
 float: left;
 animation-delay: 4s;
}


.parent div {
 animation-name: animation_01;
 animation-duration:5s;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 opacity:0;
 }

@keyframes animation_01 {
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  0%, 25%, 100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
  <nav class="navigation"> 
    <ul>
    <li class="button"> 1.0 Main Menu 
      <ul class="panel">
        <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
        <li> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>     
</div> 


<div class="parent">
 <div class="content1">Here goes content1</div>
 <div class="content2">Here goes content2</div>
 <div class="content3">Here goes content3</div>
 <div class="content4">Here goes content4</div>
 <div class="content5">Here goes content5</div>
 </div>
```

As you can see in the comments the code is divided in two parts:

**Part 1:** `Navigation` with a `panel` to display submenus when the `button` is hovered. 
**Part 2:** An automated `animation` of a `content` using CSS `keyframes`.

Both parts individually work fine.

---

Now my issue is that the `animation` of the content overflows the `panel` of the `navigation` which results from the `absolute` position of the `animation`. However, I need this `absolute` position to make the animation work since I want to have `content1` til `content5` displayed on top of each other.

On the other side I also want to have `navigation` that is not overflown by the `animation`.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this dilemma?

Comment: an animation question each hour today? :p

Comment: hahah, yeah working on something here :-)

Comment: `.header:hover + .parent {
      top: 2em;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You placed the navigation with fixed position, so if it scales it won't affect other elements in the page, the animated element in your example.

You need to place it without a fixed position. Also, you can't use scale transform since scaling it later won't affect the parent height. You can use `height: 0px` as the default state and `height: unset` once hovered.

Here's an example:

```css
/* Header & Naviagtion */
.header {
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}

.navigation>ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.panel {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  background-color: lime;
}

.button:hover .panel {
  max-height: unset;
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* Content Animation */

.parent {
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.content1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.content2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

.content3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  position: absolute;
}

.content4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  position: absolute;
}

.content5 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  float: left;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.parent div {
  animation-name: animation_01;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes animation_01 {
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="button"> 1.0 Main Menu
        <ul class="panel">
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="content1">Here goes content1</div>
  <div class="content2">Here goes content2</div>
  <div class="content3">Here goes content3</div>
  <div class="content4">Here goes content4</div>
  <div class="content5">Here goes content5</div>
</div>
```