# Change plus/minus sign of submenus if main menu is closed/opened

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following `jQuery` menu which you can also find in the JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9qahr1fv/14/):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main_menu_01, .main_menu_02").on('click', function () {
      var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
      if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
        $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500);
        $(this).hasClass('main_menu_01') ? $('.menu').removeClass('active') : $(this).removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $panel.slideDown(500);
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.main_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}

.main_menu_02 {
 padding-left: 5%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_01{
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_02{
 padding-left: 10%;
 background: lime;
}

 .main_menu_01:before, .main_menu_02:before {
 content:'+';
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.main_menu_01.active:before, .main_menu_02.active:before {
 content:'-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu main_menu_01"> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="menu main_menu_02"> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
  </ul>
  
  
  
<li class="menu main_menu_01"> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 2.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="menu main_menu_02"> 2.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 2.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 2.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
 </ul>
```

---

My issue with the code above is that when you open **all** menus each main menu changes the `+` sign to a `-` sign which is exactly how I want it.

Now when you close `1.0 Main Menu` the `-` sign of the `submenu` and the `-` sign of the `main menu` will be changed to a `+` sign which is also exaclty how I want it.

However, the issue is that when I clsoe `1.0 Main Menu` the `-` signs of `2.0 Main Menu` will also change to a `+` sign but they should stay as a `-` sign.

As far as I can see this problem appears because the code line `$(this).hasClass('main_menu_01')` triggers all classes with `main_menu_01`.

However, I could not find a way to solve this issue yet. Do you have any idea how I need to change this code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're removing the active class from all the `.menu` elements. You need to remove it only for the clicked menu and the sub menus. For that you can use `$(this).next()` and then `find('.menu')` in that context.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main_menu_01, .main_menu_02").on('click', function() {
    var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
    if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
      $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500);
      $(this).next().find('.menu').removeClass('active');
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $panel.slideDown(500);
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.main_menu_01 {
  padding-left: 1%;
  background: blue;
}

.main_menu_02 {
  padding-left: 5%;
  background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_01 {
  padding-left: 1%;
  background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_02 {
  padding-left: 10%;
  background: lime;
}

.main_menu_01:before,
.main_menu_02:before {
  content: '+';
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main_menu_01.active:before,
.main_menu_02.active:before {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu main_menu_01"> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
<ul class="panel">

  <li class="sub_menu_01"> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>

  <li class="menu main_menu_02"> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
    <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
    <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li>
  </ul>
</ul>



<li class="menu main_menu_01"> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
<ul class="panel">

  <li class="sub_menu_01"> 2.1 Sub Menu </li>

  <li class="menu main_menu_02"> 2.2 Sub Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
    <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 2.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
    <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 2.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: By the way. Do you have any idea for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378091/avoid-that-keyframe-animation-overflows-submenus-in-navigation

Answer (score 1):

First, you can just use the `.menu` class since they are both exist on both menus, the thing why it changes also is because, you use `.menu` which the function applies to both menu, you can just use `this` to apply the function your selected menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu").on('click', function () {
      $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).next('.panel').find('.panel').slideUp(); $(this).next('.panel').find('.menu').removeClass('active');
      }
});   
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.main_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}

.main_menu_02 {
 padding-left: 5%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_01{
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_02{
 padding-left: 10%;
 background: lime;
}

 .main_menu_01:before, .main_menu_02:before {
 content:'+';
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.main_menu_01.active:before, .main_menu_02.active:before {
 content:'-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu main_menu_01"> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="menu main_menu_02"> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
  </ul>
  
  
  
<li class="menu main_menu_01"> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 2.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="menu main_menu_02"> 2.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 2.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 2.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not fully work. When I open 1.0 Main Menu and then 1.2 Sub Menu and after that I click again on 1.0 Main Menu there will be a minus sign on 1.2 Sub Menu although it should be a plus sign because it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove $('.menu').removeClass('active') . Use $(this).find('.menu').removeClass('active').

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main_menu_01, .main_menu_02").on('click', function () {
      var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
      if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
        $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500);
        $(this).hasClass('main_menu_01') ? $(this).find('.menu').removeClass('active') : $(this).removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $panel.slideDown(500);
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.main_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}

.main_menu_02 {
 padding-left: 5%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_01{
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_02{
 padding-left: 10%;
 background: lime;
}

 .main_menu_01:before, .main_menu_02:before {
 content:'+';
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.main_menu_01.active:before, .main_menu_02.active:before {
 content:'-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="menu main_menu_01"> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="menu main_menu_02"> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
  </ul>
  
  
  
<li class="menu main_menu_01"> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 2.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="menu main_menu_02"> 2.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 2.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 2.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
 </ul>
```